# I would like to know what is this icon means

Tags: 15.04

I would like to know what this icon means. The one on the right.

Thanks!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjZ35.png]

Comment: networking maybe!

Comment: Well your title says WiFi. It's for configuring WiFi connections

Answer (score 1):

It is the network icon. It shows that you are connected to the internet, and is actually the Network Manager indicator icon indicating that connection.

Comment: Short and precise.

Comment: Plus minor expansion so they know it's Network manger.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Left one is weather, middle is processor frequency setter, and the one on the right is network.

Answer (score 0):

The icon at the right means that you are connected to a wireless network in ad-hoc mode.

This is actually one of Network Manager indicator icons.